# Improving SQL Performance: Many times insert or update multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

It takes long time when importing large data of excel to MySQL database, so how to improve performance?

***Excel Data likes as follows:***

**sheet_student**

| id | name | status | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | alpha | 0 | C001 |
| 1002 | alpha | 1 | C002 |
| 1003 | alpha | 0 | C003 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1501 | zip | 0 | C399 |

**sheet_course**

| course_id | course_code | course_qulity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | computer science | 99 |
| C001 | computer vision | 86 |
| C001 | computer network | 87 |
| C001 | database | 91 |
| C002 | math | 92 |
| C002 | logical | 93 |
| C002 | ai | 94 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| C299 | computer vision | 94 |

***Table of MySQL likes as follows:***

**student table**

| id | name | status | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| primary key | string | int | string |

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student`(
   `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   `status` INT,
   `course_id` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**sourse table**

| id | reference_id | course_code | course_qulity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| primary key | reference for student table primary key | string | int |

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course`(
   `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `reference_id` INT UNSIGNED,
   `course_code` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   `course_qulity` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The importing process could be describe like this:
[image]

The light gray region of the image may be improved, but I do not know how to optimize it.
Querying student table and course table with `inner join` is a good way. But `insert` and `update` operate can not work.

When excel data is too large, the importing process will take long time.

**UPDATE**

When same excel importing many times, the data of MySQL would be update according to the excel data. `name` and `course_id` field in `student` table determines row data unique or not. `reference_id` and `course_code` field in `course` table determines row data unique or not.

Comment: Provide compact Excel sample data (3-5 rows per table), MySQL initial data (structure as CREATE TABLE and, if the data present before importing may affect, some rows as INSERT INTO) and complete final MySQL tables data state for this source data after the importing, with detailed explanations.

Comment: Why not try it out, and see what happens?

Comment: Are you using a loop in VBA to select the row from the database to decide on update or insert? If so, a solution might be to create two tables student_new_data and course_new_data instead, import the complete Excel lists, and then use MySQL's `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` once for the students, once for the courses to update the whole original tables in one step.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for gaving me a way of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Databases run a lot faster when a single statement can be used to do something with/to an entire table (or a subset of a table).  Doing things one row at a time is slow.  Two batch IODKU statements can replace your flowchart.

1. Dump each Excel sheet into a CSV file.
2. Load each CSV into a staging table in MySQL.
3. Use batch operations to cleanse the data (if necessary).
4. Use batch operations to copy the data into the real tables.

By "batch" in step 4, I mean

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...;
```

or (as Thorstein mentions)

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
```

or sometimes, the 2-step process [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas to speed up the import/insert/update:

- **Remove existing indexes** - Inserting data to a MySQL table will slow down once you add more and more indexes. Therefore, if you're loading data to a new table, it's best to load it to a table without any indexes, and only then create the indexes, once the data was loaded.
- **Inserting data in bulks** - To optimize insert speed, combine many small operations into a single large operation. Ideally, you make a single connection, send the data for many new rows at once, and delay all index updates and consistency checking until the very end. In practice, instead of executing an INSERT for one record at a time, you can insert groups of records, for example 1000 records in each INSERT statement, using this structure of query:

  `INSERT INTO table_name (column_list) VALUES (value1, value2) (value1, value2), ... (value1, value2);`
- **Load data from a nearby location** - if you're loading gigabytes or terabytes of data to a remote server, keep in mind that regardless of how long it takes to actually insert records to the database, your SQL client needs to transmit that data to that server. Therefore, the network can be a significant bottleneck. Also, opening and closing connections on each insert (or group of inserts) can sum up to a large amount of time for large SQL dumps.
  Therefore, ideally, you should transmit the file to the database server once, and load it from the local filesystem.